# Displaying photos in Angular from .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, angular14

I am using .NET 6 as server-side, I have a class photo :

```
    public class Photo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a class friend

```
 public class Friend
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; } 
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public Photo photo { get; set; }
 }
```

In my controller, I have a method that passes my whole friends to the client side (Angular v14):

```
[HttpGet("returnAllFriends")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Friend[]>> ReturnAllFriends()
{
     var friends = await _context.Friends
                                 .Include(f => f.photo)
                                 .ToArrayAsync();

     return Ok(friends);
}
```

In my html page in Angular, everything displays except the photos:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let friend of friends">
      <td>{{ friend.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ friend.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ friend.lastName }}</td>
      <td>
        <img [src]="getPhotoSrc(friend.Photo)" alt="Photo" width="200" height="220" />
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here's a snippet of my new-friends.component.ts function for the photos:

```
getFriends() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5001/Friend/returnAllFriends').subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.friends = response;
        console.log('All friends retrieved');
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error occurred');
      }
    );
  }

  getPhotoSrc(photo: any): string {
    if (photo && photo.data && photo.data.length > 0) {
      const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, photo.data));
      return `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64String}`;
    }
    return '';
  }
```

No photo is displayed. Help

Comment: Typo?  The property is `photo` but you're referring to it as `friend.Photo`.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
<img [src]="'data:image;base64,' + friend.photo.data" width="200" height="220" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.